# DB structure for chat system

Tags: mysql, database

I am setting up a new table for chat system. We have three actors in our system

- Admin
- Teacher
- User

where all of them can chat with each other but only two can chat at a time (it is not a group chat).

There are no chat rooms etc. Just simple stuff.

what should be the table schema for it.

Thanks for help in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

table users

```
id  name  type
--  ----  ----
1   joe   user
2   nick  user
3   bob   admin
4   mary  teacher
```

table messages

```
id  from  to  timestamp   message
--  ----  --  ---------   -------
1   1     2   1548485505  hello
2   1     2   1548485506  are you there?
3   2     1   1548485509  YES, SORRY I WAS AFK!
4   1     2   1548485510  ok mate, no need to shout.
```

Comment: I intentionally left the following out of my answer: 1) id type 2) column types 3) column constraints 4) FKs 5) indexes 6) possible extra fields such as "seen/read", "threaded reply to" etc because this question feels homework like.

Comment: 7) login/password

Comment: @cherouvim thanks for answering but i have one issue how can i get to know who's id (user_id or admin_id or teacher_id) is stored in from and to columns.

Comment: All (or most) of your queries should join with table users to derive that information.